# Not able to update req url since req.raw is undefined in nestjs fastify custom middleware

Tags: nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

I have applied middleware to one of my application in **Nestjs Fastify**.
In middleware **I want to access userId from req url and remove it from there**. Since I was using **FastifyRequest** as a req type I was not able to reassign req.url.

I got to know that I have to use **req.raw in such case but req.raw inside middleware class is undefined for me**.

Even I found **req.originalUrl** and I tried to update it but with changed originalUrl I am getting req url not found exception.

**AbcMiddleware.ts**

```
const token = matches[0].indexOf('api') > -1 ? matches[1] : matches[0];
//(not able to reassign req.url since it is readonly property)
req.url = req.originalUrl.replace(`${token}/`, '');
//(I am getting req url not found exception with originalUrl)
req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(`${token}/`, '');
//(req.raw is undefined)
req.raw.url= req.originalUrl.replace(`${token}/`, '');
```

Comment: What is the output you want to obtain by changing the `url` property?

Comment: In fastify middleware in NestJS, `req` actually is `req.raw`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon after removing userId from endpoint will only give me correct endpoint and with userId it will be 404.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yeah that's correct but whichever requests are going through middleware... req.raw is undefined in middleware class

Comment: @Raj right, because `req` is `req.raw` so you don't need to do `.raw` to access req.raw.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thanks and correct, I noticed this now, that I am getting req.raw as a req in middleware. But now question is how can i update the current endpoint and remove userId from url?